# How can I Save the data in a file or a matrice that are displayed by this "opts = statset('Display','iter');" in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, k-means, fuzzy

I'm developing a piece of k-means fuzzy code. Now I want to save the data of each iteration that is displayed by `statset('Display','iter');`. Help me please.

```
X = [randn(20,2)+ones(20,2); randn(20,2)-ones(20,2)];
opts = statset('Display','iter');

[cidx, ctrs] = kmeans(X, 2, 'Distance','city', ...
    'Replicates',5, 'Options',opts);

plot(X(cidx==1,1),X(cidx==1,2),'r.', ...
X(cidx==2,1),X(cidx==2,2),'b.', ctrs(:,1),ctrs(:,2),'kx');
```

Comment: You might want to accept @Acorbe's solution and not mine, as it really is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dummy solution is given by the function  [`diary`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/diary.html) which enables the storing of the matlab console output on a file.

```
X = [randn(20,2)+ones(20,2); randn(20,2)-ones(20,2)];
opts = statset('Display','iter');

diary('output.txt')  % # Whatever is displayed from now on is saved on 'output.txt'

[cidx, ctrs] = kmeans(X, 2, 'Distance','city', ...
    'Replicates',5, 'Options',opts);

diary('off')         % # logging is disabled
```

After the execution, `output.txt` will contain

```
 iter    phase       num             sum
  1      1        40          96.442
  2      1         8         79.7403
  3      1         6         70.2776
 ...
```

You may want to clean the content of `output.txt` at every run, otherwise it will just append the new log after the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve would be to redirect the output displayed in the MATLAB terminal to a file, say `'my_file.txt'`. To do so:

1. Use the command `edit statset.m;` to open the file in the MATLAB
   editor.
2. Open the output file you require with `fid =
   fopen('my_file.txt','w');`.
3. Replace `fprintf(` with `fprintf(fid,`.

You might want to keep a backup copy of `statset.m` too, just to be on the safe side.

### EDIT

@Acorbe's solution gives the same result without all the above hassle.